# Read boolean from checkbox in Jade, NodeJS

Tags: node.js, checkbox, express, boolean, pug

I'm using NodeJs with Express, Jade, MongoDB, Mongoose etc.

So I have a form with a checkbox that gets POSTed in an object in my mongoDB database using Mongoose as a Boolean, true or false.

```
.checkbox
        input(type="checkbox", name="roundTrip", checked=(true || false))
```

I'm trying to use Jade to display a list of all the objects in my collection, so I passed in the an array of the objects to my `'/ridelist'` using `res.render` called `rides`.

But when I try to us an if statement in Jade to read the status of the checkbox, I get errors and it doesn't seem to work.

Here is what I want to do, but doesn't work:

```
h1.
        List of Rides
    ul
        each ride in rides
            li
                p Destination: #{ride.destination}
                p Departure: #{ride.dateLeaving} 
                p Round Trip: #{ride.roundTrip}
                if #{ride.roundTrip}     //- THIS GIVES ME AN ERROR
                    p Time departing for return: #{ride.dateReturning}
```

*Without* the last two lines it renders like:

`List of Rides
Destination: Santa Cruz
Departure: Friday 5pm
Round Trip: true
Destination: Chico
Departure: Saturday 4am
Round Trip: false`

But the *if* statement is messing me up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove brackets:

```
if ride.roundTrip
```

The statement starts from `if` so you don't need this wrapper

Also, if your `ride.roundTrip` is string in this template, you can use

```
if ride.roundTrip == 'true'
```